# Realizar subconsulta en base a una consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

como indica el título quisiera realizar una consulta a una Tabla ***"Tabla1"*** con los resultados obtenidos desde otra Tabla ***"Tabla2"***

#### **CONSULTA 1**

Para obtener los datos de la **Tabla1**

```
SELECT id FROM box_12.esale_rc WHERE kind=30;
```

lo cual me dá como resultado los campos **"id"** *(INT)* de 107 lineas:

---

```
| id  |
|-----|
| 86  |
| 436 |
| 438 |
| ... |
| ... |
```

#### **CONSULTA 2**

Antes debo mencionar que el campo involucrado en esta consulta **"detail"** *(VARCHAR)* es una cadena de texto ***("eSale invoice at De Prueba # 4")*** que dentro contiene el **"id"** que obtengo de la **Tabla1** por lo cual debo convertir y extraer los datos necesarios ***"OrdenId"***.

Para obtener los resultados de la **Tabla2**

```
SELECT id, st, detail,
 CONVERT(SUBSTR(detail,(LOCATE('#',detail) +1)), UNSIGNED INTEGER)AS OrdenId
FROM box_12.warehouse_rc
WHERE LOCATE('#',detail)>0 
ORDER BY OrdenId DESC;
```

Lo cual me da como resultado 4271 lineas:

---

```
| id   |  st |              detail               | OrdenId  |
|:----:|:---:|:---------------------------------:|:--------:|
| 4273 | 16  | eSale invoice # 5117 (Traje Baño) | 5117     |
| 4272 | 16  | Sale invoice # 5116 (Traje Baño)  | 5116     |
| 4270 | 16  | eSale invoice # 5115 (Outlet)     | 5115     |
| 4271 | 16  | eSale invoice # 5114 (Traje Baño) | 5114     |
| ...  | ... | ...                               | ...      |
| ...  | ... | ...                               | ...      |
```

### LO ESPERADO

Necesito poder hacer una consulta donde los resultados de la **Consulta1** las (107)lineas sean las condiciones para que la **Consulta2** me de sólo los id de los 107 resultados esperados.

todo esto con la finalidad de hacer un UPDATE posterior al campo **st**

saludos, espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: puedes hacer `select consulta2 where id in (consulta1)`, es lo que quieres?

Comment: @JackNavaRow Tan simple, obtuve lo necesario, claro que sólo obtuve 89 resultados, tendré que hacer análisis.

Gracias.

Comment: @JackNavaRow por favor agrega tu comentario como respuesta.

Comment: si me das mas detalle se podria hacer con un inner join

Answer (score 1):

resolví ayer gracias a @JackNavaRow

> puedes hacer select consulta2 where id in (consulta1), es lo que quieres? – JackNavaRow

de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT id AS wrcId, st AS wrcSt, detail AS wrcDetail,
    CONVERT(SUBSTR(detail,(LOCATE('#',detail) +1)), UNSIGNED INTEGER)AS ordenId
FROM box_12.warehouse_rc
WHERE LOCATE('#',detail)>0 AND id IN(
SELECT id FROM box_12.esale_rc WHERE kind=30)
ORDER BY OrdenId DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar subconsultas , basado en tu pregunta lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:

***Usando SubQuery dentro del SELECT:pero no te servirar el order By***

```
    SELECT  
        (SELECT id, st, detail,
                CONVERT(SUBSTR(detail,(LOCATE('#',detail) +1)), UNSIGNED INTEGER)AS OrdenId
            FROM box_12.warehouse_rc
           WHERE LOCATE('#',detail)>0
             AND box_12.warehouse_rc.id =  box_12.esale_rc.id)
        ORDER BY OrdenId DESC) 
  FROM box_12.esale_rc 
 WHERE kind=30;
```

***Usando Subquery en el WHERE y/o HAVING***

```
SELECT id, st, detail,
       CONVERT(SUBSTR(detail,(LOCATE('#',detail) +1)), UNSIGNED INTEGER)AS OrdenId
FROM box_12.warehouse_rc
WHERE LOCATE('#',detail)>0 
AND (SELECT id FROM box_12.esale_rc  
      WHERE kind=30
        AND box_12.esale_rc.id = box_12.warehouse_rc.id);
ORDER BY OrdenId DESC;
```

***Por ULTIMO USANDO Inner Join esta ultima sera la mas rapida***

```
SELECT id, 
       st, 
       detail,
       CONVERT(SUBSTR(detail,(LOCATE('#',detail) +1)), UNSIGNED INTEGER)AS OrdenId
  FROM box_12.warehouse_rc 
 INNER JOIN box_12.esale_rc  on (box_12.esale_rc.kind=30 AND box_12.esale_rc.id = box_12.warehouse_rc.id)
 WHERE LOCATE('#',detail)>0 
 ORDER BY OrdenId DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno yo haria el siguiente query:

`SELECT id, st, detail,
 CONVERT(SUBSTR(detail,(LOCATE('#',detail) +1)), UNSIGNED INTEGER)AS OrdenId
FROM box_12.warehouse_rc
WHERE LOCATE('#',detail)>0
AND id in (SELECT id FROM box_12.esale_rc WHERE kind=30)
ORDER BY OrdenId DESC;`

agregue la siguiente linea a tu segundo query:

`AND id in (SELECT id FROM box_12.esale_rc WHERE kind=30)`